# What does it mean when somebody says "Result is not Thread-Safe"

Tags: java, multithreading, hbase

I was writing an app specific wrapper over Java HBase APIs when I read this doc:

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html

It says `This class is **NOT THREAD SAFE**.`

What exactly does it mean by not thread safe. I'm basically a C++ programmer and if someone says the function `strtok()` is not thread safe, I'll not use it in a multithreaded env. Its something like `strtok()` uses a static variable and calls to this function by two different threads is not a good idea.

Is it the same when it comes to JAVA?

I have a function:

```
public String get(String key, String family) {
    Get get = new Get(key.getBytes());
    get.addFamily(family.getBytes());

    Result result = null;
    try {
        result = _table.get(get);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

The function get might be called by multiple threads. Does it make Result unsafe to use somehow?

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: Unfortunately, a thing can be "not thread-safe" in many different ways.

Comment: To get a definitive answer, you'd have to ask the author.

Comment: what is `_table` in your method?

Comment: _table is HTableInterface that I get from HTablePool. Does it matter :O?

Answer (score 4):

> What exactly does it mean by not thread safe.

It means that if the given class object is accessed via various `Threads` then calling its method(s) within those `Threads` may result in unpredictable results because of unwanted interaction between the various `Threads`. The basic reason for this unpredictable result is the sharing of same `data` of an `object` among various `threads`. You can look at here at [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) to know more about Thread-safety.

After going through your code I am seeing that you are using a member variable `_table` in line `result = _table.get(get);` . So , most probably it is not `Thread-safe`.

Answer (score 3):

If a class is "not Thread-Safe", its methods cannot be called (on the same instance) by multiple threads without additional synchronization. For example, you can't simultaneously iterate over an ArrayList in one thread, and modify its contents in other.

In your case it shouldn't be a problem, because in each invocation of function get new instance of Result is created, so these threads operate on different Result objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you read that Result is not thread safe it means that if you have a situation where multiple threads can access this result object you need to make sure the usage is synchronized (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for list of ways to synchronize access).

If your code will stay as is, i.e. each call to get will generate its own new instance of Result you are ok. If you'd keep this Result instance between calls in the object and it will be used in multiple calls you'd need to protect the access to that Result object